# adding time to date fields

Tags: trigger, date

so im building an app that will run for a certain time from a start date to an end date so i have a start_date__c and end_date_*c and i have a pick list duration*_c which allows the user to select the duration. I want to build a trigger that auto assigns the end date according to the start date and the duration.

For example heres psudo:

```
trigger{
   if(duration__c == "One Month"){
      end_date__c = start_date__c + *Month*;
   }
   else if(duration__c == "One Year"){
      end_date__c = start_date__c + *Year*;
   }
}
```

what i need is how to do the *Month* or *Year* part is it possible to do this? If so could someone help me out on how im a little lost.

PS: the * are only for purposes of demonstrating

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Date`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm) methods to create new dates:

```
trigger updateEndDate on XYZ__c (before insert, before update) {
    for(XYZ__c record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.Start_Date__c != null) {
            if(record.Duration__c == 'One Year') {
                record.End_Date__c = record.Start_Date__c.addYears(1);
            }
            if(record.Duration__c == 'One Month') {
                record.End_Date__c = record.Start_date__C.addMonths(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep gettin a NULLPointerException with this either on your first line, or when i take that line out the next line

Comment: For some reason, `record` is null. Can you update your question with the code you've tried so far?